# C# code running locally but not in web hosting

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications

in my asp.net web application i have this entity framework code snippet that work perfectly in local

```
CONNECTIONS_STATS cs = new CONNECTIONS_STATS();
cs.CS_ID_USER = 5211;
cs.CS_DATE = DateTime.Now;

using (var dbCtx = new ModelEntities())
{
  dbCtx.CONNECTIONS_STATS.Add(cs);
  dbCtx.SaveChanges();
}
```

but when i deploy it to my web host, i have this error at line

```
dbCtx.CONNECTIONS_STATS.Add(cs);
```

> CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet.Add(MyAPP.CONNECTIONS_STATS)' has some invalid arguments

in the detailed compiler output

> error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'CONNECTIONS_STATS' to 'MyApp.CONNECTIONS_STATS'

i have **checked** that all the classes are in the same namespace , and like i said this code **Work** perfectly in local

any idea on this please ?

Comment: You probably have old binaries you'll need to clear out and redeploy.